# Kafka producer metrics not appearing in Spring Boot 3.1.1 Prometheus

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot 3.1.1 component on which I just created some Kafka producers. I wish to expose their metrics in Prometheus, so I made the following configuration:

```java
@Autowired
private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, StatusEvent> statusEventKafkaTemplate(KafkaConfig kafkaConfig) {
  var config = kafkaConfig.buildProducerProperties();
  var factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, StatusEvent>(config);
  factory.addListener(new MicrometerProducerListener<>(meterRegistry));
  return new KafkaTemplate<>(factory);
}
```

However, when I check Prometheus, all that is there is `spring_kafka_template_seconds_max` and `spring_kafka_template_seconds`.

I saw in another project that they have a load more: `kafka_producer_request_latency_avg`, `kafka_producer_record_retry_total`, etc. They are using `org.springframework.kafka.core.reactive.ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate`, but I wish (if possible) to find a solution that works with `org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate`.

Here are the properties I think are relevant:

- application.properties

  ```
  management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
  management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
  management.endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS
  spring.config.import=classpath:kafka-properties.yaml
  ```
- kafka-properties.yaml

  ```
  spring:
      kafka:
          bootstrap-servers: [...]
          security:
              protocol: SASL_SSL
          properties:
              sasl:
                  mechanism: PLAIN
                  jaas:
                      config: [...]
              producers:
                  client-id: [...]
                  acks: all
  kafka:
      properties:
          status-events:
              template:
                  default-topic: [...]
              producer:
                  key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
                  value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
          [...]
  ```

I tried adding spring-boot-starter-actuator and micrometer-registry-jmx to my dependencies, to no avail. I tried with `spring.jmx.enabled=true` in my properties. I already have micrometer-registry-prometheus in my dependencies.

What am I missing for the producer metrics to appear in the actuator? Or is this not possible, and I should switch to reactor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, my configuration was correct. It turns out that as long as a producer does not send anything, the metrics don't show up in the actuator.